# Using CAST to filter for day prior in SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to filter SQL results to only return records with yesterday's date in the `tblname.SYSTEM_DATE` column. Would the below clause return all records with a `SYSTEM_DATE` value equal to yesterday's date or would it only return results with a `SYSTEM_DATE` value within the last 24 hours? If the latter, how could I rewrite it to instead return all records with yesterday's date?

```
WHERE (tblname.SYSTEM_DATE = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as date)))
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What do you get when you `SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as date))`?

Comment: Is `tblname.SYSTEM_DATE` a `date` or `datetime`?

Comment: @DaleK I am getting varying results based on the time of day that I execute the query, which makes me think its taking time into consideration, but the datatype of the column is `date`.

Comment: And what happens when you run the select in my first comment? And please provide some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @cheese that is not possible if tblname.SYSTEM_DATE is DATE column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a `DATETIME` column you can use use:

```
WHERE tblname.SYSTEM_DATE >= CAST(CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
AND tblname.SYSTEM_DATE < CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
```

If it's a `DATE` column then your posted query should work.

Note that `GETDATE()` will return the current `DATETIME` based on the timezone for SQL Server.  So you are subtracting 1 day from that and finding all the rows that match that exact date.  This won't work with a DATETIME colunn but will work with a DATE column.  Timezone differences could be an issue though.  You also have `GETUTCDATE()` to return the current date/time in UTC.